# Why does a Shiny app get disconnected when not used for a while?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny app running in a Shiny server that is installed on a Ubuntu 16.04 server.

When the app is loaded in a browser but not run for a while, it gets disconnected.

Is there a solution that prevents this?

Comment: Maybe a connection issue, as shiny communicates with clients via a constant WebSocket connection...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to put a repeating signal into your server function that worked for my app to be kept alive:

```
#Keep App alive
keep_alive <- shiny::reactiveTimer(intervalMs = 10000, 
                                        session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain())

shiny::observe({keep_alive()})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually disable [`app_idle_timeout`](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-timeouts) for good by setting it to 0 in your Shiny server config file:

```
location / {
    app_idle_timeout 0;
}
```

Comment: That is cool. @anddt Where would you store this file? And does it also work when hosting the app not on shinyserver?

Comment: When using [`shiny-server`](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server) to host a Shiny application the config file can be found at `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution, but I have a case where the Shiny server runs in a Kubernetes environment where the settings cannot be changed since they are hidden. Then janderkran's solution is your only option.

Comment: @Wilbert uh, k8s wasn't mentioned in your question. But generally yes, if deployed that way `shiny-server.conf` would be meaningless and the only way is to keep-alive the app itself (watch out for server load if the app is pulling large data).